# Java / Selenium application - how do I get the session id of the application under test?

Tags: java, selenium

I am working with Java and Selenium, and trying to get the session id of the application under test after it has logged in. I found this bit of code, but it gives me the session id of the driver. This is no use to me. I want the session of the app I am running.

```
SessionId sessionId = ((FirefoxDriver) driver).getSessionId();
```

Comment: I'm not aware that apps have session ids.  Do you mean the process ID from the operating system that the JVM is running under?

Comment: Sorry. I got that completely wrong. My java application is an automated test. The session id I want is the one for the application being tested.

Comment: with Firefox, I press F12, then go to the Network tab, where it is shown amongst the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way :

```
WebDriver seleniumDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
 try {
 String domainString = "http://yourURL";
 String baseUrl = domainString;
 seleniumDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 seleniumDriver.get(baseUrl + "/Login.aspx/");
 seleniumDriver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
 seleniumDriver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("username");
 seleniumDriver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
 seleniumDriver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");
 seleniumDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.primary.btn")).click();
 String ASPNET_SessionId = seleniumDriver.manage().getCookieNamed("ASP.NET_SessionId").toString();
 System.out.println(ASPNET_SessionId);
 }
 finally {
 seleniumDriver.close();
 }
```